# Can I construct an update query in postgres where the columns to update are nested in a case?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, case

Is there a way in postgres to update multiple columns with a single case clause? I've only ever seen it done the other way around--that is, multiple case clauses for each column:

```
update table
set col1 = case when condition then value1 else value2 end
set col2 = case when condition then value3 else value4 end
where ...
```

But what if I want to update several columns and the condition in the case clause is the same for all of them? Wouldn't it be more consise to have a syntax that allows the case clause to be written once and each column nested inside it? Something like this:

```
update table
case when condition then
    set col1 = value1, col2 = value2, ...
else
    set col1 = value3, col2 = value4, ...
end
where ...
```

Is this possible in postgres?

Comment: Well your question "Wouldn't it be more concise ..." may very well be true, but it  is not an available option. Nor at this point is it available from latest SQL Standard.